# Extend/Change extensions in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-4.5

I wanted to ask, how to change files in a TYPO3-Extension, that they wont be overwritten after an update of the specific extensions.
I know that there are 'hooks', but they only give me some functions, not the hole controller file of an action.

Are there some best practices or do I only have the option to never update that extension?

Greets
Agash Thamo.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on various factors.

**Extbase Extensions**

If the Extension is based on Extbase, you could write your own Extension with your custom Controller and use the domain model of the original extension. Since you didn't really specify which extension you want to modify, this is only a general approach.

**Hooks**

Are not necessarily provided by extensions. You can always ask the extension author to provide a new hook.

**XCLASS**

With XCLASS, you can overwrite a class from your own extension. You can find more information about this [here](http://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS). If you update the original extension, you probably need to adjust your XCLASS code.

**Directly modify an existing Extension**

You should avoid doing this. But if it is your only option, you can modify the file "ext_emconf.php" of the extension and set "state" to "excludeFromUpdates":

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'Extension Title',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => 'plugin',
    'state' => 'excludeFromUpdates',
    ...
);
```

This excludes an extension from updates.